# Can`t find the solution,how do i solve it

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you
>   can use "null !== expression" instead) in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\loginregister\profile.php on line 15

I use it to get msg from my database file

```
<?php if (isset($_GET('msg') )) { echo "<span style='color:green'>".$_GET('msg')."</span>"; } ?>
```

Comment: <?php 
if (isset($_GET('msg') )) {
  echo "<span style='color:green'>".$_GET('msg')."</span>";
}
?>  i use it to get msg from my databse file

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET` is an *associative array* of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.

So you have to access the `msg` like `$_GET['msg']`

Try this:

```
<?php 

if ( isset( $_GET['msg'] ) ) { 
      echo "<span style='color:green'>" . $_GET['msg'] . "</span>"; 
} 

?>
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

we can not use an expression in isset.

The isset () function is used to check whether a variable is set or not.

for example if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))

if you want to use expression the you should use if statmet like

```
if($_REQUEST['submit']==''){}else{}
```

or

```
if($result >=0 or $result ==''){}else{}
```

if you want a specific answer, please mention your condition